# If $(a, b)=1$, then $1+ab$ is not a proper factor of $a^2+b^2$ .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b$ be integers such that $(a, b)=1$ and suppose that $1+ab|a^2+b^2$. I am asked to prove that this is possible only if $1+ab=a^2+b^2$.

First $a^2+b^2$ is a sum of coprimes squares, thus any odd prime divisor is of the form $p=1(4)$. The only even factor, if exists, can only be $2$. Thus as a divisor $1+ab$ also satisfies the previous condition. Now we want to prove that this is never possible unless $1+ab=a^2+b^2$. Can this line of thought lead to a solution?

Moreover, recall the well-known problem that $\displaystyle\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}=(a, b)^2$ when the quotient is an integer(Note that $a, b$ do not need to be coprime). How can we apply the above result on this problem?

Comment: Assuming your last paragraph is true, doesn't your question immediately follow?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes obviously. But I am looking for a different proof, for example, in a easier case above when $a, b$ are coprime.

Comment: Ah, you asked "how can we apply the above result on this problem", instead of "is there an easier proof". Please rephrase the question to indicate what you want.